# Curl output not working by adding if at the end

Tags: php, curl

Hi guys I use this curl to get page content and echo that. with simply `return $data;` it worked but after adding `if ($data == "Playing PlusMW3"){ ...` at the end of curl code its not working, can someone tell me what is wrong?!

```
function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);             // Use POST method
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=1&var2=2&var3=3");  // Define POST data values
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //return $data;

    if ($data == "Playing PlusMW3"){
        return "<img src=\"./friends/assets/img/plusmw3.png\" alt=\"OfFline\">";  
    }elseif ($data == "Playing PlusOPS2"){
        return "<img src=\"./friends/assets/img/plusops2.png\" alt=\"OfFline\">";
    }elseif ($data == "Playing PlusOPS"){
        return "<img src=\"./friends/assets/img/plusops.png\" alt=\"OfFline\">"; 
    }elseif ($data == "offline"){
        return "<img src=\"./friends/assets/img/offline.png\" alt=\"OfFline\">"; 
    }else{
        return $data;
    }
}

$stat = get_data('http://plusmaster.ir:13060/pe/95/__body');
echo $stat;
```

Comment: It's `elseif` not `else if`.

Comment: "not work" tells us practically nothing. What about an error message? **Note**: I would recommend using `strcmp` for string comparison, or at least `===`.

Comment: You should `var_dump($data)` to make sure you're receiving whatever it is you're expecting... possibly even use `trim()`.

Comment: there is no error just blank page. i am wondering if data format in html format so can this is effected that?! if yes how i can fix and receive data?!

Comment: @Half Crazed with var_dump($data) i have this result:  string(17) "Playing PlusMW3 "

Comment: My comment provides the answer to your issue. See string(17)? This means there's 17 characters, but you're only checking for 15..

Comment: Do you have it set to display errors? If not add this to the top of your php page: `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` As @HalfCrazed mentioned: `"Playing PlusMW3" != "Playing PlusMW3  "`.

Comment: yes there is no errors i just have this:   string(17) "Playing PlusMW3 "

Comment: And? What are you expecting it to be? Is `return $data;` called as expected? As I just said you have trailing spaces. So `if ($data == "Playing PlusMW3")` will not be called (if that is what you are trying to do). Use `trim()` as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip out trailing spaces from the result:

```
$data = trim($data);
if ($data == "Playing PlusMW3") { //... then the rest should remain unchanged
```